# TCL- How to interpret a string as multiple arguments in tcl procedures?

Tags: string, function, split, tcl, procedures

I have a procedure that needs to accept a set amount of parameters to make arrays. I have a csv file with the information for the parameters on each line. Using the command *[split $line ,]*, returns the information with spaces in between except that procedures treat it as one argument instead of 7 or 8 arguments. How can I get a csv line, such as the following:

```
 day-month-year,34,3,12,5,1,54,21,$big money
```

to be seen as multiple arguments such as:

```
 date num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 money
```

or a variation such as the following:

```
 day month year num1 ... num7 big money
```

The split command returns:

```
 date num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 {big money}
```

which is fine except that it is treated as a single argument. My call looks like this:

```
 procName [split $line ,]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Tcl version 8.5 or later:

```
procName {*}[split $line ,]
```

If you are using Tcl version 8.4, the {*} construct was yet to exist, you have no choice, but to do something like:

```
eval procName [split $line ,]
```

Be warned, the eval might be unsafe, especially if the input comes from unknown sources.

#### Update

The {*} construct is called *Argument Expansion*. All I know about it is this:

```
procName {*}{a b c}
```

is the same as:

```
procName a b c
```

This feature was proposed in the Tcl Improvements Proposal (TIP) [293](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/293.html) and was discussed in the [Tcl'er Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9468).

Comment: The `eval` will be fine here; the static part looks fine, and the non-static part is a proper list (i.e., it comes out of `split` which does proper list construction).

Comment: The {*} construct did it, no errors, thank you!! Where can I find more information on the {*} construct?

Comment: @Harrichael: To see doc about `{*}`, see the man page of `Tcl`. Or you can find it online here: [Argument expansion](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9 "www.tcl.tk").